# Custom Spinner contain drawable and string

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I want to create a custom spinner containing icon and string but the value taken from resource array.
The issue is when I run the app it won't launch. But that doesn't happen when I declare the array inside the activity
by declaring I mean this: `String[] vcode = {"d1","d2","d3","d4","d5"};`
I already move those variable to `oncreate`, but the icon didn't show up in my application. Why?

Following is what I had done so far and failed. Please tell me where did I go wrong

res/values/array.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer-array name="d_icon">
        <item>@drawable/d1</item>
        <item>@drawable/d2</item>
        <item>@drawable/d3</item>
        <item>@drawable/d4</item>
        <item>@drawable/d5</item>
    </integer-array>
    <string-array name="d_code">
        <item>d1</item>
        <item>d2</item>
        <item>d3</item>
        <item>d4</item>
        <item>d5</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="d_condition">
        <item>1</item>
        <item>1</item>
        <item>1</item>
        <item>0</item>
        <item>1</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Hello"
        />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

custom_spinner_items.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:text="Demo"
        android:textColor="#000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.training.androidcustomspinner;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    //String[] vcode = {"d1","d2","d3","d4","d5"};
    //int vicon[] = {R.drawable.d1, R.drawable.d2, R.drawable.d3, R.drawable.d4, R.drawable.d5};
    String[] vcode = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.d_code);
    int vicon[] = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.d_icon);

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        CustomAdapter customAdapter=new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(),vicon,vcode);
        mySpinner.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    }
}
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
package com.training.androidcustomspinner;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    int vicon[];
    String[] vcode;
    LayoutInflater inflter;

    public CustomAdapter(Context applicationContext, int[] vicon, String[] vcode) {
        this.context = applicationContext;
        this.vicon = vicon;
        this.vcode = vcode;
        inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return vicon.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner_items, null);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        TextView names = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        icon.setImageResource(vicon[i]);
        names.setText(vcode[i]);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your xml files?

Comment: ok, I'll edit the post and add it.

Comment: What is the issue ?

Comment: The issue is when I run the app it when on error and won't launch. But that doesn't happen when I declare the array inside the activit @Vickyexpert

Comment: by declaring I mean this(sorry If wrong word being used) : String[] vcode = {"d1","d2","d3","d4","d5"}; @Vickyexpert

Comment: @user3931627 Because you have declare values outside onCreate method therefore, if you want to access values from resources then access it inside onCreate method

Comment: @Vickyexpert You were right about declaring value. I already move those variable to oncreate, but the icon didn't show up in my application. Why?

Comment: @user3931627 for that you need to use typedArray instead of int :

Like 

TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.random_imgs);

Comment: @Vickyexpert thank's man, you were correct

Answer (score 0):

my adapter extend ArrayAdapter and implement getDropDownView, and it works for me. like follow

```
public class SimpleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    public SimpleAdapter(Context context, int resource, String[] objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }

    public SimpleAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }

    public SimpleAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, String[] objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    public SimpleAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
    }
}
```

Comment: didn't work for me, can you show me how did you do yours ?

Comment: with arrayadapter or baseadapter onlywork when you do this : String[] vcode = {"d1","d2","d3","d4","d5"}; but not this
    String[] vcode = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.d_code)